# Fill the date field if you have value of other filed

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I have sharepoint 2013
I have list with two columns. 
First column is STATUS (choice type = not startet, in progression, finish) 
Second column is FINISH_DATE (date type).
I need automatic fill.
When i choose FINISH in Status column the system should automatic fill FINISH_DATE with today's date.
I have no idea how to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but this should be a simple workflow that triggers on edit. Open up SharePoint Designer and create a new workflow on the list. This should be the logic:

```
If Status equals FINISH
  Set FINISH_DATE to Today
```

Comment: thank you,  this formula is exactly what I want, but I have problem with syntax in sharepoint (syntax error, function not supported)

Comment: This would be a workflow, not a calculated column